# Using Django's cache if and only if the user is logged-out?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I need to implement caching on my Django 1.8 site (to speed up rendering, obviously). Plan is to use Memcache, although this question isn't directly tied to it.

Right now, a lot of traffic goes to a specific set of blog posts that remain constant. But, there is a universal dynamic topbar across the whole site which can vary from logged-in user to logged-in user, so I need a cache function that kicks in if and only if the user is anonymous - e.g. one that is bypassed altogether if the user is logged in.

It looks like Django's builtin cache doesn't really distinguish between logged-in and logged-out users, so if I use it, there will be adverse effects for logged-in people.

I'll probably have to write my own cache decorator/cache function using the lower-level cache API and attach it to all of the logged-out-accessible URLs/views on the site. While it doesn't *seem* difficult, this does seem like an incredibly common feature. Is there really nothing in Django that does this properly already? I'm worried I might have missed something and am reimplementing the wheel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First of all template caching is over rated. First use django debug toolbar to determine if template rendering is indeed slow on your django installation. I am betting that it's not the bottleneck. If you find that it's slow. YOu can cache on a per user basis as follows:

```
{% cache 300 FULL_PAGE request.build_absolute_uri request.user %}
```

The first parameter to the [cache template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) is the timeout and the second one is the name others uniquely identify the fragment.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I see how this can be used on a per-user basis.

Template rendering in this case is not the bottleneck. What is the bottleneck is the fact that the template is populated by several database calls (since the actual content is stored in elephantblog/feincms). Hence, I need to cache at the URL / controller layer, before it even makes those calls.

Comment: this can also be used for non auth users because then the user will be anonymous for all of them. Yes, caching all or part of the queries in memcache might give you a much better speed improvement